# Type 'String' is not a subtype of Map<Dynamic, Dynamic>

Tags: flutter

I have a dart file that stores the list of map of country names and dial codes. The format is thus...

```
countries = List<Map> countries = [ { "name": "Afghanistan", "dial_code": "+93", "code": "AF" }, { "name": "Åland Islands", "dial_code": "+358", "code": "AX" } ]
```

I imported it into my main file with my buttondropdown file and tried using the map function on it.

```
                      child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_city,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
                            items: countries
                                .map((Map<String, String> dropDownStringItem) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: dropDownStringItem,
                                child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                print(value);
                              });
                            },
                          ),
```

[image]

Am trying to make the dropdown show just the names. But I get the error type 'String' is not a subtype of type Map. WHat am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Specifying type `Map` by itself will make the compiler assume that it is of type `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`. You need to change this line:

`items: countries.map((Map dropDownStringItem) {`

To this:

`items: countries.map((Map<String, String> dropDownStringItem) {`

Comment: I did that and I got another error. 'The argument type 'DropdownMenuItem<Map<String, String>> Function(Map<String, String>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(Map<dynamic, dynamic>)'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)'

Comment: Can you paste the whole `items` function that you have now for me?

Comment: You edited an additional line. Revert `return DropdownMenuItem<Map<String, String>>(` to what it was before.

Comment: Still got the same error. The argument type 'DropdownMenuItem<String> Function(Map<String, String>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(Map<dynamic, dynamic>)'

Comment: Can you include each time what your new code is? I feel like you're changing something else each time because the errors are new.

Comment: Alright. Just edited it to it's most current state.

Comment: Yeah, you haven't reverted it to its original state. It's `return DropdownMenuItem<Map>` not `return DropdownMenuItem<String>`!